# App get crashed for Israeli users

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, special-characters

`enter code here`I am facing a strange from last 4 days. I have an app which is kind of a social network app. In which user can register themselves with the following information.

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Log in email id
4. Passord
5. Current location (Which is city name,state which is taken using MKReverseGeocoder)

users are able to register without any issue but as soon as they log in the app get crashed. this is happens only for **Israeli** users. I am not able to get what would be the issue for crashing. **for other country users it is working fine like US, India etc**.

can any one have any idea about this.

This is crash log :

```
Incident Identifier: 03C1B44D-0630-4F1D-AC8F-C354D0BAA418
CrashReporter Key:   15804dd53bc675e7292476ab76de6b082c74f9a3
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         IWAZ [1031]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/08D509AF-9FD2-41D4-888E-A5D76DA11E86/IWAZ.app/IWAZ
Identifier:      IWAZ
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-07-12 17:38:56.372 +0300
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xe0000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37cc7f78 0x37cc4000 + 16248
1   MapKit                          0x32a1f746 0x32a0c000 + 79686
2   CoreFoundation                  0x358851f4 0x3586d000 + 98804
3   Foundation                      0x35449740 0x353a5000 + 673600
4   CoreFoundation                  0x358faacc 0x3586d000 + 580300
5   CoreFoundation                  0x358fa298 0x3586d000 + 578200
6   CoreFoundation                  0x358f903e 0x3586d000 + 573502
7   CoreFoundation                  0x3587c49e 0x3586d000 + 62622
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3587c366 0x3586d000 + 62310
9   GraphicsServices                0x37518432 0x37514000 + 17458
10  UIKit                           0x33388cce 0x33357000 + 203982
11  IWAZ                            0x0000286c 0x1000 + 6252
12  IWAZ                            0x00002824 0x1000 + 6180

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361cc3a8 0x361cb000 + 5032
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x347b6f04 0x347b3000 + 16132
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x347b6c22 0x347b3000 + 15394

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361cc004 0x361cb000 + 4100
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361cc1fa 0x361cb000 + 4602
2   CoreFoundation                  0x358fa3ec 0x3586d000 + 578540
3   CoreFoundation                  0x358f9124 0x3586d000 + 573732
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3587c49e 0x3586d000 + 62622
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3587c366 0x3586d000 + 62310
6   WebCore                         0x3177bc9c 0x316d2000 + 695452
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32ce972e 0x32cdb000 + 59182
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32ce95e8 0x32cdb000 + 58856

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361cc004 0x361cb000 + 4100
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361cc1fa 0x361cb000 + 4602
2   CoreFoundation                  0x358fa3ec 0x3586d000 + 578540
3   CoreFoundation                  0x358f9124 0x3586d000 + 573732
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3587c49e 0x3586d000 + 62622
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3587c366 0x3586d000 + 62310
6   Foundation                      0x353b5bb2 0x353a5000 + 68530
7   Foundation                      0x353b5a7a 0x353a5000 + 68218
8   Foundation                      0x3544958a 0x353a5000 + 673162
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32ce972e 0x32cdb000 + 59182
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32ce95e8 0x32cdb000 + 58856

Thread 4 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361cc004 0x361cb000 + 4100
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361cc1fa 0x361cb000 + 4602
2   CoreFoundation                  0x358fa3ec 0x3586d000 + 578540
3   CoreFoundation                  0x358f9124 0x3586d000 + 573732
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3587c49e 0x3586d000 + 62622
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3587c366 0x3586d000 + 62310
6   WebCore                         0x317a50d2 0x316d2000 + 864466
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32ce972e 0x32cdb000 + 59182
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32ce95e8 0x32cdb000 + 58856

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361dc570 0x361cb000 + 71024
1   CoreFoundation                  0x358fe63a 0x3586d000 + 595514
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32ce972e 0x32cdb000 + 59182
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32ce95e8 0x32cdb000 + 58856

Thread 6 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361dc068 0x361cb000 + 69736
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32ce9a46 0x32cdb000 + 59974
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32ce97c2 0x32cdb000 + 59330
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x3080d90e 0x30748000 + 809230
4   WebCore                         0x318dcbdc 0x316d2000 + 2141148
5   WebCore                         0x318dcb92 0x316d2000 + 2141074
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32ce972e 0x32cdb000 + 59182
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32ce95e8 0x32cdb000 + 58856
```

Thans in advance.

Comment: This is a long shot. But can it have something to do with parsing israeli characters, Hebrew?

Comment: this can be a font/character issue.

Comment: Could you post the crash log, this might really give a clue as to what is happing. You can get the crash logs from iTunesConnect.

Comment: I have tested by sending Hebrew and israeli characters in the address field but it works for that characters without any issue. Really Big issue for me.

Comment: I am not able to post crash log in comment area. from where I can do this ?

Comment: Edit your original post to include relevant crash log information.

Comment: Just update the question with crash log. One more thing is if some one using an account created in India then it works in israeli.

Comment: @rckoenes Did you get any thing from crash log ?

Comment: @jattt.... can you [simbolize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports) the crash log so we can read it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement `reverseGeocoder:didFailWithError:` ? Does it show any error? Maybe some places are not solved and you are facing an issue with a variable not set.

Comment: Yes I have Implemented it. I am getting the city name in the database no issue with null values. One more thing is if some one using an account created in India then it works in israeli.